# when i try to decrypt my message in python it says 'string index out of range' in line 8

Tags: python

my code just rearranges the string so that every odd index is moved to the front then the even indexes are moved to the back. now I want to know how do I decrypt this

```
s = input('please enter a string: ')
for i in range(1,len(s),2):
    s =  s[ : :2] + s[1: :2]
print('encrypted:',s)

c = input('type your encrypted message to decrypt: ')
for i in range(0,round(len(c)//2,0)+1,2):
    c = c[ :i] + c[len(c)//2 +1 + i] + c[i+1: ]
print(c)
```

Comment: You do not need a loop in the first part of your code: `s =  s[::2] + s[1::2]` suffices.

Comment: Your encryption doesn't do what you say it should. When I input `0123456789` the result is `0516273849`, not `1357902468`.

Comment: You don't need to use `round()`, since `//` rounds down automatically.

Comment: When `i == len(c)/2`, `len(c)//2 + 1 + i` will be `len(c) + 1`, which is too large.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and see if it's what your looking for.

```
s = input ('Please enter a string : ')

# incrypt
s = s[::2] + s[1::2]
print (s)

# decrypt
s += ' '
d = ''
half = int (len (s) /2) 
for i in range (half) : d += s [i] + s [i + half]
print (d)
```